# Best way to access PHP super-global variables in Laravel 5.x config file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, config

I need to use one parameter from global variable `$_SERVER` in my config file (app.php), so that I can access `SERVER_NAME` and define which static resource server to use.

```
$staticUrlMap['local.example.com'] = 'localstatic.example.com';
$staticUrlMap['dev.example.com'] = 'devstatic.example.com';
$staticUrlMap['stage.example.com'] = 'stagestatic.example.com';
$staticUrlMap['preprod.example.com'] = 'preprodstatic.example.com';
$staticUrlMap['my.example.com'] = 'static.example.com';

$staticUrl = '';
if(!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
{
    $staticUrl = $staticUrlMap[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']];
}

return [
    'static_url' => $staticUrl,
];
```

Is there a better way to achieve this other than using `$_SERVER` directly in laravel-config file?

Comment: Whats wrong with using `$_SERVER`, in fact I would think it's more readable because I don't know Laravel. But I been coding PHP for almost 7 years and certainly know what $_SERVER is.  P.S - I really hate frameworks that use sensless wrappers around built in functionality, so I may be a bit Biased.  That said one word of caution - when running PHP from the command line ( CLI ) I don't think Server name will exist, if memory serves me.

Comment: You're right @ArtisticPhoenix, when running from CLI it won't have $_SERVER and that's why I have !empty check to avoid warnings that I get while I run "php artisan" commands.

It's been decade since I am into programming but new to Laravel and thought it doesn't hurt taking expert advice so just coined in as a question here.!

Comment: Yea it's because the CLI doesn't run inside of apache so there is no server.  Nice to meet you.

Comment: that's true, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the `Request` façade to access the `$_SERVER` super-global.

```
echo Request::server('SERVER_NAME');
```

As an opinion side note, I generally agree with @ArtisticPhoenix's comment about readability and distaste for framework wrappers around basic functionality. However, using the wrappers for super-globals makes it a lot simpler to unit test. Also, of little relevant importance, there are some popular style guides out there that will fail you for direct access of the super-globals.